# Large JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have large json files and I need to return them from Web API using .NET 6.
Some metadata should be added, so the DTO looks like this

```
public class Response
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public T Content { get; set; }
}
```

Tried to use Utf8JsonWriter, no luck. It doesn't have api to write stream.
Is there a way to stream file without allocationg it in memory?

```
await using var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(Response.Body, new JsonWriterOptions{SkipValidation = true});
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WriteNumber("Id", 1);
writer.WritePropertyName("Content");
writer.WriteRawValue(GetStream(filePath));  // there is a way to do this?

await writer.FlushAsync();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why can't you stream using `Utf8JsonWriter`? It seems to work just fine for your stated purpose.

Comment: Sorry, add some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either fully buffer the file into a `byte` array and write that using  `WriteRawValue`

```cs
await using var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(Response.Body, new JsonWriterOptions{SkipValidation = true});
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WriteNumber("Id", 1);
writer.WritePropertyName("Content");

await using var file = GetStream(filePath);
var buffer = new byte[file.Length];
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
writer.WriteRawValue(buffer, true);
writer.WriteEndObject();
await writer.FlushAsync();
```

Or you can stream it in. You cannot use `WriteRawValue` for this, as it requires a single value. Even with `SkipValidation`, it will mess up the state of the writer, so you need to write the property name and the value directly to the underlying stream.

```cs
await using var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(Response.Body, new JsonWriterOptions{SkipValidation = true});
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WriteNumber("Id", 1);
await writer.FlushAsync();  // you MUST flush the JSON writer first
await Response.Body.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"""Content"":"));
var buffer = new byte[4096];
await using var file = GetStream(filePath);
await file.CopyToAsync(Response.Body);
writer.WriteEndObject();
await writer.FlushAsync();
```

Comment: I tried second approach, but it failed. This method needs single valid JSON value according to the JSON RFC

Comment: Interesting. `WriteRawValue` has a `SkipValidation` parrameter, which is `true` here, so it should work. Could be badly implemented. You will have to do the first option and buffer the whole thing

Comment: No, it won't work. The only way is to buffer a whole file. "Thrown if <paramref name="skipInputValidation"/> is <see langword="false"/>, and the input is not a valid, complete, single JSON value according to the JSON RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259)or the input JSON exceeds a recursive depth of 64".

Comment: I saw that. But I am passing `true` for that parameter, so it should work according to the docs. I'm not disagreeing with you, I'm just saying the docs and what happens don't match

Comment: OK looks like `WriteRawValue` needs to have a single value, have modifed the second version